# What can cause this error, Failed to send. KafkaException Unexpected error in InitProducerIdResponse. The request timed out

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka producer is unable to send messages at times and gives following error

```
 KafkaException Unexpected error in InitProducerIdResponse. The request timed out
```

Comment: Please show your code as a [mcve]. As the error says, it's a timeout. Your configs can override many request timeout settings

Comment: We are not overriding any timeout settings

Comment: Still, please show your code with an [edit]. You asked what can cause it, and the answer is - "the network". So, maybe you **should** override some settings to increase the timeout window